# Reload Google Ads within same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, adsense

We have a page on our site that users may stay at for a long time without being reloaded. We would like the google adsense ads to reload sometimes based on a click event, would the following Javascript function do the trick or is there more to it?

```
function reloadAds(){
    $("#adDiv").html(AD CODE HERE);
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should consider reloading the page rather than injecting the ad code: Google will find/ban you for a violation of their terms and conditions.

```
function reloadAds() {
    location.reload();
}
```

Comment: neat solution, though I doubt the users will enjoy the continuous reloading of the whole page.

Comment: Agreed. Pages like DrudgeReport.com do this to keep their content fresh (and to add up more pageview metrics). This makes me unhappy and I feel dirty for having posted it. ;)